# Google Home no longer broadcasting messages from the SDK (10/17/2019)

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

Until yesterday, I was able to broadcast messages across my several google home speakers in my house.  I've been using either the assistant-relay project (https://github.com/greghesp/assistant-relay) or the google-assistant-webserver project (https://github.com/AndBobsYourUncle/hassio-addons).  Either project worked perfectly for the last year.

Has something changed in the last day/week?

Yesterday, I noticed I could send a command such as "What time is it?", or "What is the weather?", and it would return the appropriate weather or time.  However, if I issued a "broadcast" command of text, or even using one of their precanned recorded messages (bed time, movie time, etc), the message was never broadcasted.  Additionally, the MyActivity section of google shows that "You asked the Assistant to broadcast a message" and from the SDK.

Has something changed?  Are we no longer able todo broadcasting programmatically?